# Dependency issues while updating through Discover app in kali linux kde

Tags: kali-linux, kde, dependencies, software-updates

Whenever I try to update my existing system files and software using the Discover app in my kali linux kde, I get some certain dependency resolution errors, which halts the whole update process. And even using my terminal, I cannot update those packages.
Here I am enclosing the image of the scenario.
[image: Updates:Discover]

And here I am enclosing the screenshot of the terminal.
[image: Terminal]
Can anyone tell me a way to resolve the issue??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gcc-10 base was creating the issue. So I used this commands:

```
sudo apt clean
sudo apt update -m
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt install -f
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt autoremove --purge
```

The package manager could not resolve the issue on its own. So, I had to remove the packages using the autoremove -- purge command.